# primefaces outputText html

Tags: html, post, primefaces

I have a String in my Bean which actually holds a post form. I display this page using outputText:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{myBean.stringHtml}" />
```

The html is being displayed correctly. This page contains a post form, where I want to save some data in by bean where the submit button is pressed.
I want somehow a listener to this button that is contained within the String. Is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking. Are you proposing that stringHtml contains a button that you would then bind to a listner on your backing bean? Or is your commandbutton in a line after the outputtext?

Comment: There is a button in stringHtml that when is pressed I want to save some information in a bean. There is no commandbutton in my page.

Consider that stringHtml contains a html page with a button inside it

Comment: I am not sure how that would work. I suppose you could try binding it to a actionlistener but I wouldn't think it would work. I think you probably would be better re-designing your presentation. You tagged this a PrimeFaces. What components are you using? Perhaps if you posted more complete code we could come up with some alternatives for you.